# Value not being removed from dictionary

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift-dictionary

I have a dictionary in Firebase called `peopleWhoLike`, the key is an auto-id and the value is the uid of the user who liked, I'm trying to loop through the `peopleWhoLike` dictionary and find the entry with the current users uid as the value so that I can remove it, but the value is not being removed.

```
func removeLike(postID: String){
    ref.child("posts").child(postID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let info = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
            if var peopleWhoLike = info["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : String]{
                print("peopleWhoLike - \(peopleWhoLike)")
                for person in peopleWhoLike{
                    if person.value == FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid{
                        peopleWhoLike.removeValue(forKey: person.key)
                        print("personkey - \(person.key)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Both print statements print correctly, ie `person.key` being the correct key

[image: Screenshot]

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: can you `print(peopleWhoLike)` before remove and after remove and copy it as text?

Comment: you should read only ontime at beginngn `let currentUserUid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid` to speedup some calls

Comment: where the likes should removed?

Comment: I'm trying to remove the dictionary entry which has the value of the current users uid from the peopleWhoLike dictionary, i tried printing peopleWhoLike straight after removing the value and its seems to be removing the value(as its printing the dictionary without the value inside of  it), but there are still no changes in firebase though.

Comment: you wand it only remove from the dictionary or you want to remove it from firebase?

Comment: then you need to save this at firebase. you get only an copy of data from firebase!

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have only an snapshot (a copy) of the data there

to remove the value from the firebase database;
try this:

```
//path should be like this (i guess):
let currentUserUid = FIRAuth.auth()!.c‌​urrentUser!.uid
ref.child("posts")
   .child(postId)
   .child("peopleWhoLike")
   .chi‌​ld(currentUserUid)
   .rem‌​oveValue()
```

or same:

```
let currentUserUid = FIRAuth.auth()!.c‌​urrentUser!.uid
ref.child("posts/\(postId)/peopleWhoLike/\(currentUserUid)").rem‌​oveValue()
```

**UPDATE**

you you like to remove the person key - then you can:

a) iterate over peopleWhoLike and find if it is the user ( but please put this `let currentUserUid = FIRAuth.auth()!.c‌​urrentUser!.uid` outside the loop!

```
//path should be like this (i guess):
let currentUserUid = FIRAuth.auth()!.c‌​urrentUser!.uid

// loop and when match `person.value == currentUserUid` then:
ref.child("posts")
   .child(postId)
   .child("peopleWhoLike")
   .chi‌​ld(person.key)  //<-- change here
   .rem‌​oveValue()
```

b) you search in the query. and remove then the resulting node.

```
ref.child("posts")
   .child(postId)
   .child("peopleWhoLike")
   .startAt(currentUserId)
   .endAt(currentUserId)
   . [...] do something
```

i dont know if you can direct call `.removeValue()` at this point. but with a SingleEvent and an snapshot you can do `snapshot.ref.removeValue()` - doublecheck before you delete. but since this results in a reference you should direct able to call `.removeValue()`

```
ref.child("posts")
   .child(postId)
   .child("peopleWhoLike")
   .startAt(currentUserId)
   .endAt(currentUserId)
   .removeValue()
```

note: this search takes longer than a direct path

see here doc for query:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html#byemail

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#delete_data

**NOTE:**

i would advice you to save it with the `userUid` as key because you only need a onliner to delete (see my first codesnippet where you not need to get all data from `peopleWhoLike`) and as value just 1 or you can save the current date (then you know when it was liked)

Comment: I tried doing something similar to that, the problem is FIRAuth.auth()!.c‌​urrentUser!.uid is the value, and auto id is the key, so FIRAuth.auth()!.c‌​urrentUser!.uid is not the child of peopleWhoLike

Comment: i dont understand: in the comments you say - yes it is removed from `peopleWhoLiked` as key - and now you say its different? you should print a list (or screenshot of the data under `peopleWhoLiked`) - i ask you before to add a printout from `peopleWhoLike` to your question!

Comment: then you switch it.

Comment: peopleWhoLike is the dictionary, person is the entry in the dictionary, auto id is the key and the users uid is the value, and i said it removed the current users uid from the peopleWhoLike dictionary.

Comment: btw: bad idea not to save the auto id ;) - updated my answer